# adding html to a php function

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, function

I am trying to customize a bootstrap template for *cmsimple* but am failing.

The original function looked like this:

```
function bootstrap_li() {
    global $h, $hc, $l, $s;

    $html = '<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-top">' . "\n";

    foreach ($l as $index => $level){
        if ($level > 1){
            continue;
        }

        if (hide($index)){
            continue;
        }

        if ($s == $index){
            $html .= '<li class="active"><a href="#">' . $h[$index] . '</a></li>' . "\n";
        }
        else {
            $html .= '<li>' . a($index, '') . $h[$index] . '</a></li>' . "\n";
        }
    }

    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

Since every list element should have its own background image that is swapped if the list link is the actual page, I changed it to this:

```
function bootstrap_li() {
    global $h, $hc, $l, $s;

    $html = '<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-top";">
    <li><a class="nav-about" href="/?About">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-members" href="/?Members">Members</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-calendar" href="/?Calendar">Calendar</a></li>' . "\n";

    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

...which works except for that the active link does not change its style.
i wanted to make this work by entering an if-loop, e.g.:`

```
function bootstrap_li() {
    global $h, $hc, $l, $s;

    $html = '<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-top";">
    <li><a class=" ' . "\n";

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/?About.php'){
      echo 'hover.nav-about';
  } else {
    echo 'navb-about';
  }

$html .= '
    " href="/?About">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-members" href="/?Members">Members</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-calendar" href="/?Calendar">Calendar</a></li>' . "\n";

    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

...but this does not work. In the browser the list element is echoed without link tag and without the assigned CSS styles.

I assume that I am not using the syntax correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things which seem pretty wrong on first glance. Apart from "if-loops" not being a thing (its just ONE desicion and action) you also only echo your class attributes instead of adding it to your $html variable at:

```
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/?Über-uns.php'){
  echo 'hover.navbutton-ueber-uns';
 } else {
echo 'navbutton-ueber-uns';
 }
```

for example it shoud look like this

```
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/?Über-uns.php'){
  $html.= 'hover.navbutton-ueber-uns';
 } else {
 $html.= 'navbutton-ueber-uns';
 }
```

apart from that i dont see anything obvious wich woud indicate something wrong, so i woud recommend to just try it and update with your results.